# About the fft function

Tags: julia, fft

Does anyone know which algorithm is used in Julia to perform the fast Fourier transform? The documentation only says:

```
...
A one-dimensional FFT computes the one-dimensional discrete Fourier transform (DFT) as defined by

\operatorname{DFT}(A)[k] =
  \sum_{n=1}^{\operatorname{length}(A)}
  \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi
  (n-1)(k-1)}{\operatorname{length}(A)} \right) A[n].
...
```

In particular, I have a discrepancy in my transformed data, i.e. this transformed data is "shifted" a phase of  I think `pi`. Is there a convention to fix this global phase?

EDIT: 
Perhaps it's worth saying that if I perform the inverse fft, then the discrepancy in the phase is corrected.

Comment: Data is shifted with respect to what? What are you seeing and what are you expecting? I'd be very surprised if Julia's FFT didn't compute the same thing all other FFTs compute. The only difference you typically see is in the normalization, which some people prefer one way and other people prefer in another. But that difference is just a real constant, no change is phase should be expected.

Comment: It was ok. Still, do you know which algorithm Julia uses for the fft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia uses the FFTW library, I believe, which uses several variants of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm, as described in the reference below.

http://www.fftw.org/fftw-paper-ieee.pdf